# Add new key value pair to object - REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask if someone can help do the following.

How do I add a new key value pair to an existing object that I have inside an array fetched from an API. 
Basically, after fetching from API I have an array name utils which has the response.

```
// utils = [ 
{
 id: 1,
 item: 10,
 name: "candybar" 
},
{
 id: 2,
 item: 12,
 name: "whitechocolatebar"
}
]
```

now I have written some conditional statements for whenever like the following:

```
for (i in utils){

 if(utils[i].name == "candybar"){

  utils.push({ new_name : "Candy Bar" });

 }else if(utils[i].name == "whitechocolatebar"){

  utils.push({ new_name : "White Chocolate Bar" });

 }else{

  utils.push(utils[i].name);

 }

}
```

now this gives me :

```
utils = [
{
 id: 1,
 item: 10,
 name: "candybar" 
},
{
 id: 2,
 item: 12,
 name: "whitechocolatebar"
},
{
 new_name: "Candy Bar"
},
{
 new_name: "White Chocolate Bar"
}
]
```

But i want to have the array utils in the following manner:

```
utils = [
{
 id: 1,
 item: 10,
 name: "candybar" ,
 new_name: "Candy Bar"
},
{
 id: 2,
 item: 12,
 name: "whitechocolatebar",
 new_name: "White Chocolate Bar"
}]
```

Can someone help me achieve this?

Kind Regards and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
utils = utils.map(item => {
let new_name = item.name;
if(item.name === 'candybar'){
   new_name = 'Candy Bar';
} else if (item.name === 'whitechocolatebar'){
   new_name = 'White Chocolate Bar';
}
return ({ ...item, new_name });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know was map function, as I am a little new to React native. Thanks again thou.